# How do i add some text characters to a text line and return the remaining text after after result

Tags: php, split

I have the code:

```
$txt = "showandreturn";

$disp = str_split($txt, 2); 

for ($b = 0; $b<3; $b++) {
    echo "$disp[$b]"; 
}
```

which return 'sh,ow and an 'in a text line of 'showandreturn' my problem is how do i add some characters 'ENDED' and return the remaining result example my result of 'showandreturn' after split look like 'showanENDEDdreturn' and 'dreturn' thanks for your time and understanding

Comment: What is this `$b<$3`?

Comment: @kisaragi sorry dat is $b<3;

Comment: And I'm assuming line one should be `$text`? and `$disp` in the loop?

Comment: Yes can i really achieve this in php?  @kisaragi

Comment: Fix your question code, you have $txt and $text, $disp and $displ, ...

Comment: You should update the question to better reflect what it is you're looking to do. For example: What is 'a certain' text split? Always after 6 letters? Always in the middle?

Comment: @Nic is fixup now thanks do you have any solution or idea to my problem?

Comment: Your current code only displays `showan`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make two `for` loops one from 0 to 3 and the second from 3 to number of array elements.

```
$text = "showandreturn";
$disp = str_split($text, 2); 
$num = 3;
for($b = 0; $b<$num; $b++){
    echo $disp[$b]; #showan
}
echo 'ENDED';
for($b = $num; $b<sizeof($disp); $b++){
    echo $disp[$b]; #dreturn
}
```

and the output is `showanENDEDdreturn`

**EDITED**

```
$text = "showandreturn";
$disp = str_split($text, 2); 
$num = 3;
for($b = 0; $b<$num; $b++){
    echo ' '.$disp[$b];  #sh ow an
    $shown .= $disp[$b]; #showan
}
echo ', '.$shown.'ENDED'; #showanENDEDdreturn
for($b = $num; $b<sizeof($disp); $b++){
    $dreturn .= $disp[$b]; #dreturn 
    echo $disp[$b]; #dreturn
}
echo ', '.$dreturn;
```

This is the new code new output `sh ow an, showanENDEDdreturn, dreturn`

Comment: thanks for your time and impact but that is not what i really wanted my result should output example
'sh ow an, showanENDEDdreturn, dreturn'
just like 
first_output 'sh' 
second_output 'ow'
3th_output 'an'
4th_output 'showanENDEDdreturn'
5th_output 'dreturn'

Comment: @Eniedi Monday Answer Edited :), i hope its work as you wish, if there is any problem, please comment it.

Comment: Can i put the result into a variables and also get a good result example
$text = "showandreturn";

    $disp = str_split($text, 2); 

    $num = 3;

    for($b = 0; $b<$num; $b++){

        $outputa = "$disp[$b]"; 
#showan

    }

    $outputb = "ENDED";

    for($b = $num; $b<sizeof($disp); $b++){

        $outputb = "$disp[$b]";
echo "$outputa$outputb$outputc";

    }

Comment: @Eniedi Monday yeah if you understood how it work, you can do whatever you want, It's a pleasure to helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

$txt = "showandreturn";

$disp = str_split($txt, 2); 
$disp = str_replace($disp, $disp . "ENDED", $txt);

Answer (score 0):

While you have the array of each 2letters from the text and you want to add “ENDED” after 3rd index then use if statment to check if it is third then add “ENDED” to it not that array is zero index to you have to compare to 2

```
$txt = "showandreturn";
$disp = str_split($txt, 2); 
for ($b = 0; $b<count($disp); $b++) {
echo "$disp[$b]"; 
if($b==2){echo "ENDED";}
}
```

Comment: You should explain what the OP did wrong, and how your code fixes it